# type for useState with callback - Type has no call signatures

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am using `useState` with a callback:

```js
interface Props {
  label: string;
  key: string;
}

const [state, setState] = useState<Props[]>([]);


setState((prev : Props[]) => [...prev, newThing])
```

I get the error:

`2349: This expression is not callable. Type 'Props' has no call signatures.`

I'm not sure how to define a call signature inside the Props interface/type, what is the best approach to resolve this?

**Edit:**

This is how I am using it inside my code:

Interface:

```js
interface TagProps {
  left: string;
  top: string;
  backgroundColor: string;
  rotation: number;
  label: string;
  key: string;
}
```

Home.tsx

```js
const Home: FC<TagProps> = (setState, state: TagProps[]) => {
  const createTag = (e: any) => {
    const tagSpec = {
      left: e.clientX + "px",
      top: e.clientY + "px",
      backgroundColor: randomColour(colors),
      rotation: randomNumber(-20, 20),
      label: tech[randomNumber(0, tech.length - 1)],
      key() {
        return this.label + this.backgroundColor;
      },
      position: "absolute",
    };
    setState((prev: TagProps[]) => [...prev, tagSpec]);
  };

...

}
```

App.tsx

```js
function App() {
  const [tag, setTag] = useState<TagProps[]>([]);

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
          <Route index element={<Home setState={setTag} state={tag} />} />
          <Route path="/blog" element={<Blog />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you provide short snippet where you can reproduce this problem. I'm not able to do it [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-silence-5bo4b7?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: There is no error. See [here](https://tsplay.dev/N9PE1w)

Comment: Can you post a sandbox link reproducing the error and also, can you share the screenshot of the console output?
Your Component's Type definition is incorrect. You have passed TagProps to FC so, your  props structure should actually be: ` {left, top, ...etc } ` but, you are expecting: setState and state.
I suggest that you console.log your `setState` to check its type and contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to [desctucture](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/es6/javascript-object-destructuring/) your props

```
// from
const Home: FC<TagProps> = (setState, state: TagProps[]) => {

// to
const Home: FC<TagProps> = ({ setState, state }) => {
```

Also I wouldn't pass `setState` down to the component

Answer (score 0):

React Functional Component's property are under the first param, you can do this to get them

```js
const Home = (props) => {
  const { state, setState } = props;

  // setState(...)
}
```